# Switch / select case etc. compared to If ... ElseIf ... Else

Tags: javascript, readability, conditions, switch-statement

I don't understand why the `switch` or equivalent is so popular in languages. To me, it seems like it had a place back in the days when the alternative was lots of nested `if` statements in the `else` part of other `if` statements. Now that we have `else if`, why do we need it?

If we take the following:

```
switch (expr) {
  case "Oranges":
    document.write("Oranges are $0.59 a pound.<br>");
    break;
  case "Apples":
    document.write("Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>");
    break;
  case "Bananas":
    document.write("Bananas are $0.48 a pound.<br>");
    break;
  default:
    document.write("Sorry, we are out of " + expr + ".<br>");
}
```

It is clearly more readable than below?

```
if (expr == "Oranges") {
    document.write("Oranges are $0.59 a pound.<br>");
} else {
    if (expr == "Apples") {
        document.write("Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>");
    } else {
        if (expr == "Bananas") {
            document.write("Bananas are $0.48 a pound.<br>");
        } else {
            document.write("Sorry, we are out of " + expr + ".<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

But how is it more readable than:

```
if (expr == "Oranges") {
    document.write("Oranges are $0.59 a pound.<br>");
} else if (expr == "Apples") {
    document.write("Apples are $0.32 a pound.<br>");
} else if (expr == "Bananas") {
    document.write("Bananas are $0.48 a pound.<br>");
} else {
    document.write("Sorry, we are out of " + expr + ".<br>");
}
```

Comment: There is a large school following some mantra like 'the less chars is better to read' or something on that line. Your last example still has a few extra braces, repeats `expr ==` over and over again. All in all introducing a few more places where you could have a typo or miss a detail. But mostly it's a matter of personal preferences and primarily opinion based (chances are question will be closed for that, there is not really a clear answer and discussions are off topic on Programmers.SE)

Comment: because switch has different semantics from if/else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now we have else if

In many language specifications, Java certainly being among them (I'd have to look up Java*script*), else if isn't a thing. You have `if (expr) {block} [else statement]` where an if statement is itself a statement. I'm not sure there are many languages in which the idea of an "else if" has been impossible.

Switch/case statements originated because they allowed the compiler to create a jump table, allowing one to create a large number of different "paths" without necessarily having to pay for n comparisons. A [jump table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table) can save a fair number of instructions, and once that really mattered. You can view a case statement as a goto label even now.

These days the differences are less relevant, but some think that switch/case better shows intent.

Personally I'm more inclined to agree with your conclusion, that it isn't necessarily any more readable and introduces conceptual wobbles with a case label being logically a "block" but not actually scoped as one.